# How to fetch model with pre-defined array of items and do update and delete in SwiftUI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, save, swift-data

I'm new to swiftui and i am trying to load the defined array in the model that i have adjusted  example code form the xcode when you open a new project. in my case i want to load the array of dates which it is succsfuly loaded but the deleteItems function shows index error when i delete item from the model.

> Cannot assign to property: 'items' is a get-only property

and

> Type 'Item' has no member 'all') in this part of the code :items = try modelContext.fetch(Item.all()

and also another error in the testApp code:

> Thread 1: "Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0. The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (2), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). Collection view: <SwiftUI.UpdateCoalescingCollectionView: 0x107870e00; baseClass = UICollectionView; frame = (0 0; 414 896); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c74a80>; backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x6000017894c0; name = systemGroupedBackgroundColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000027c5e0>; contentOffset: {0, -92}; contentSize: {414, 143}; adjustedContentInset: {92, 0, 34, 0}; layout: <UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: 0x10720be10>; dataSource: <_TtGC7SwiftUI31UICollectionViewListCoordinatorGVS_28CollectionViewListDataSourceOs5Never_GOS_19SelectionManager")

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData

@Model
class Item: Identifiable {
    var timestamp: Date
    
    init(timestamp: Date) {
        self.timestamp = timestamp
    }

    // Define a static array of pre-defined dates
    static let preDefinedDates: [Date] = [
        Date(),
        Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), // Adding one day
        Date().addingTimeInterval(2 * 86400) // Adding two days
    ]
}




import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

@main
struct testApp: App {
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([
            Item.self,
        ])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}
```

and this the view code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var items: [Item] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                ForEach(Item.preDefinedDates, id: \.self) { predefinedDate in
                    NavigationLink {
                        Text("Item at \(predefinedDate, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))")
                    } label: {
                        Text(predefinedDate, format: Date.FormatStyle(date: .numeric, time: .standard))
                    }
                }
                .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
            }
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    EditButton()
                }
                ToolbarItem {
                    Button(action: addItem) {
                        Label("Add Item", systemImage: "plus")
                    }
                }
            }
        } detail: {
            Text("Select an item")
        }
    }

    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Item(timestamp: Date())
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }

    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            // Print the items array and offsets for debugging
            print("Items before deletion: \(items)")
            print("Offsets to delete: \(offsets)")

            for index in offsets {
                guard index < items.count else {
                    print("Index out of range: \(index)")
                    continue
                }

                let itemToDelete = items[index]
                modelContext.delete(itemToDelete)
            }

            do {
                try modelContext.save()

                // Update the items array after deletion
                items = try modelContext.fetch(Item.all())
                print("Items after deletion: \(items)")
            } catch {
                print("Error saving after deletion: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
        .modelContainer(for: Item.self, inMemory: true)
}
```

i expect it to delete the item and not show it again in the list after relaunching the app`your`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run your code and it has a bunch of strange errors caused by you not fully understanding how to use SwiftUI, SwiftData or data sources. So first of all if you are learning SwiftUI then do not use SwiftData because it's to much to learn both at once.

To start with you are mixing two data sources that are completely independent of each other, your static array and your persisted model `Item`.

The first thing you should do is to remove `Item` and anything related to SwiftData from your project.

Then to make the array into a proper data source for your view code move it into the content view and turn it into a `@State` property

```
@State private var preDefinedDates: [Date] = [
    Date(),
    Date().addingTimeInterval(86400), // Adding one day
    Date().addingTimeInterval(2 * 86400) // Adding two days
]
```

Change your delete function to

```
private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        preDefinedDates.remove(atOffsets: offsets)        
    }
}
```

And change or remove the `addItem()` function, if you have removed all SwiftData code you can now run your app and delete will work as expected.

*If you insist on also using SwiftData then you need to do the opposite, remove your static array and use the query property `items` where you today uses the array. Note that `@Query` will keep the array up to date, you do not need to do that manually.*

Comment: Thank you for testing the code, your comment directed me to choose the right approach to my use case. I removed swift data and used array and it worked.